# How do I use Excel Power Query with AutoDesk Takeoff?

Tags: powerquery, autodesk-forge, autodesk-construction-cloud

I am new to using both AutoDesk Construction Cloud API and Excel Power Query.

I have a sample curl request from the documentation:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer nFRJxzCD8OOUr7hzBwbr06D76zAT" "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b.d6cf8c84-c25e-4534-ae5c-62e08480e751/projects"
```

I know both my bearer  token and the hub id which is after the 'hubs' portion in the url. The ones I list here are from the documentation sample, taken from here: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/getting-started/retrieve-account-and-project-id/

I don't understand where I would input these credentials in Power Query to get a response from this request.
I'm seeing an option for using an API key, but I don't think I am given one.

I have Excel installed locally but I have Office 365.

I receive the error in Power Query that says 'A web API key can only be specified when a web API key name is provided.'
I have attempted to use advanced instead of basic and add a header for Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx portion.

I have tried adding autodesk-platform-services tag as instructed but it does not appear to exist.

Comment: Would you characterize this is as a question about programming or software development?

Comment: Their help forum says to post on here and they're supposed too respond. But the tag they give doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to use ACC takeoff API, you should firstly follow the tutorial to get the 3 legged token as https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/, this will be used for the following request as Authorization parameter in Header, please make sure to get a valid 3 legged token first.

I am not experienced in Excel Power Query either, but by search, I found this post to add header in your http request:
https://docs.x-formation.com/display/LICSTAT/Using+the+API+with+Microsoft+Excel+and+Power+Query

Answer (score 0):

I received feedback from AutoDesk. It does not appear possible to get the 3 legged token using Power Query.